# How the dependency class constructor is invoked before the dependent class constructor in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

I have written the following code using Spring framework.

**CODE**

```
package com.spring.core.trialDI;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.spring.core.trialDI")
class LegendConfig {

}

@Component
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("I am A constructor!");
    }
}

@Component
class B {
    A a;

    public B() {
        System.out.println("I am B constructor!");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setA(@Qualifier("a") A a) {
        System.out.println("I am setA of B!");
        this.a = a;
    }
}

@Component
class C {
    A a;

    public C() {
        System.out.println("I am C constructor!");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setA(@Qualifier("a") A a) {
        System.out.println("I am setA of C!");
        this.a = a;
    }
}
public class TrialTheory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LegendConfig.class);
        B b = applicationContext.getBean(B.class);
        C c = applicationContext.getBean(C.class);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I am A constructor!
I am B constructor!
I am setA of B!
I am C constructor!
I am setA of C!
```

Now as in `main()` method, I have created a bean of `B` type first, so the constructor of `class B` must have called first even before the setter. (Constructor creates the object and its method can only be used after its creation).

But why `A`s constructor is called before anyone? What's going on behind the scene?

Comment: This an implementation artifact. Spring likely evaluates that the creation of bean B and C requires bean A, so it will create bean A before creating and initializing bean B and bean C. It could use a different order, but I think that will lead to far more complex initialization than this order.

Comment: Also, given these are context scoped/singleton beans, they will be created when the context is initialized, not when you ask for the bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `B b = applicationContext.getBean(B.class);` does not mean that you create a bean (if it's a singleton bean, as in your example). It only gives you an already created bean from context. Spring creates singleton beans during its startup (during the application context creation phase).

You can read more about how spring manages beans here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans.html

Comment: Your answer is true for default scoped beans, but if it was a prototype scoped bean it would create B when `getBean` is invoked.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good note, I've updated my answer